# Choosing a matplotlib backend for a specific IPython profile

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

`matplotlib` has a config file and `IPython` has its own. Which one has precedence when it comes to setting things like `matplotlib` backends?

For example, say my config file for `matplotlib` says to use a specific backend, but then I modify my IPython startup or config files to use a different one. Which one would be used when I start IPython and import `matplotlib`?

More generally, what is the *right way* to set things up so that different profiles use different `matplotlib` backends or matplotlib configurations?

Comment: Why not test it yourself? Set option=A in one file, set option=B in the other, start IPython and see which option is set?

Comment: http://tonysyu.github.io/mpltools/ at least gives you a nice way to separate config into several profiles. I would prefer to just call a method directly in your notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPython configuration is used, as IPython itself chooses the matplotlib backend.

For reference, see [IPython:core/pylabtools.py:activate_matplotlib](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/pylabtools.py#L274) and notice how `matplotlib.use(backend)` is called explicitly.